# Java: How to build an array of a given length with random index's taken from another array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm working on my own little project and I'm having a small issue.

Lets say I have a String array `{"Green","Blue"}`.

I want to be able to make a new array of some length, lets say for example 100, with each index 0-100 being randomly selected from the above String array so I should get:

```
{"Green", "Green", "Blue", "Green", "Blue", "Blue", "Green", ... "Blue"}
```

It seems really simple I don't know why I'm having a hard time. If anyone could help me solve this in a very simple way, I am trying to test my logic not my knowledge of code. Thanks!

Comment: Show us your logic then! What **part** is hard?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I initialize the initalArray = {"Green", "Blue"}, then I use a for loop with a random index generator that will output either 0 or 1 which represents green or blue, and then I get lost because I don't know how to assign a length value to an array without it containing the elements already.

Comment: `String strArray[] = new String [100];`

Comment: *I don't know how to assign a length value to an array without it containing the elements already* - maybe that should have been your question

Comment: You said my answer was satisfactory. Can you please accept it?

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is set the array's size to 100, then add random indexes of your first array into your second one. Here's one way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random(); //used for adding random places of array
    String[] array = {"Green","Blue"}; //creates new array
    String[] array2 = new String[100]; // makes size of array 100

    for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) { //executes until 'array2' s full
        int index = rand.nextInt(2); //chooses a random index of 'array'
        array2[i] = array[index]; //adds that spot to 'array2'
        //System.out.println(index); //uncomment to prove that it is adding random things
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));` - before the next question comes

Comment: Boom thats exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @user8335068 please accept it if this answer what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I would generate random values with a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), `limit` it and then convert it to an array. That could be done with something like,

```
String[] array = { "Blue", "Green" };
Random rand = new Random();
String[] out = Stream.generate(() -> array[rand.nextInt(array.length)]) //
        .limit(100).toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(out));
```

Comment: Although great and efficient , But won't be working below java 1.8

Answer (score 1):

`Random#ints(long streamSize, int origin, int bound)`
returns a stream producing the given `streamSize` number of pseudorandom int values,
each conforming to the given `origin` (inclusive) and `bound` (exclusive).

```
String[] array = { "Blue", "Green" };
String[] result = new Random().ints(100, 0, array.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> array[i])
    .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple enough, somthing like whats below.

```
for(String item : largeArray){
    int randomIndex = (int)(Math.random() * smallArray.length);
    item = smallArray[randomIndex];
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with your for loop format, could you explain that?

Answer (score -1):

I used to generate random numbers in the past too. In order to do a true random generation, I invite you to use random.org java library. You can find it here: [CLICK](https://sourceforge.net/projects/trng-random-org/)

It is true that this is a client and requires internet connection, but if you want to go professional, I invite you to dive in this library.

You can also use the java basic library, simply using Math library However, this is a pseudo random number generator. Read this article. [CLICK](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_random.htm)

After you decide which type of randomness you'd like to pick, you simply iterate:

```
RandomIntegerClient cl = new RandomIntegerClient("youremail@foo.bar");
List <String> myRandomIntegers = 
    cl.getRandomIntDecimal(0, initialArray.length, finalArray.length);
for (int i = 0; i<finalArray.length; i++) {
    finalArray[i] = initialArray[Integer.parseInt(myRandomIntegers.get(i))]
}
```

By the way, I prefer the Random.org method, as for big data its features are pretty substantial.

Please note that this 'for' format is standard. You can also use an iterator, as the other user has shown (`for String iteratorExample:myList)`). There is no efficiency gain. It's just fancier to write it that way. for(;;) is fine and until you learn about iterators, you can stick to it.

Good luck with learning java and welcome to SO!

Comment: Lists are essentially the only way to assign elements to an undefined length array, correct?

Comment: No. Not really. You can have empty arrays of defined sizes. For example String [ ] foo = new String [55] { };  This is an empty strings array of size 55.

Comment: No. Not _at all_! just declare it's size: `String[] s = new String[10]` BOOM! an array is made with a size of 10.